# How i can combine these Linq query and how improve query speed

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have this SQL script that I need to convert to Linq for use with EF Core:

```
SELECT  
    A.*, B.*
FROM
    [Orders] AS A
JOIN
    (SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
     FROM [OrderMeta]
     ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderId ORDER BY PostDate DESC)
    ) AS B ON (b.OrderId = A.OrderId)
```

Here is what I converted this to:

```
public async Task<List<GetAllOrdersResult>> AdminGetOrderList()
        {
            using (var db = new SoulDrawContext())
            {
                var query = from A in db.Orders
                            join B in db.OrderMeta
                            on A.OrderId equals B.OrderId
                            select new GetAllOrdersResult
                            {
                                OrderId = A.OrderId,
                                UserId = A.UserId,
                                OrderDate = A.OrderDate.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                Currency = A.Currency,
                                Amount = A.Amount,
                                PaymentMethod = A.PaymentMethod,
                                ShipTo = A.ShipTo,
                                Status = B.Status,
                                PostDate = B.PostDate.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"),
                                RefOrderId = A.RefOrderId
                            };
                var query1 = from a in query
                             group a by a.OrderId
                             into g
                             orderby g.FirstOrDefault().PostDate
                             select new GetAllOrdersResult
                             {
                                 OrderId = g.FirstOrDefault().OrderId,
                                 UserId = g.FirstOrDefault().UserId,
                                 OrderDate = g.FirstOrDefault().OrderDate,
                                 Currency = g.FirstOrDefault().Currency,
                                 Amount = g.FirstOrDefault().Amount,
                                 PaymentMethod = g.FirstOrDefault().PaymentMethod,
                                 ShipTo = g.FirstOrDefault().ShipTo,
                                 Status = g.FirstOrDefault().Status,
                                 PostDate = g.FirstOrDefault().PostDate,
                                 RefOrderId = g.FirstOrDefault().RefOrderId
                             };
                return await query1.ToListAsync();
            }
        }
```

**Problem:**

The SQL script running in SSMS is working fine, query takes about 32 ms to complete, but the linq query by EF core takes about 9600 ms.

There are about 2,000 records in `order` table, and 60,000 records in `ordermeta` table.

**TODO**

1. How can I convert the SQL script to Linq correctly? (or combine 2 linq queries?)
2. How can I improve query speed?

Comment: are you using the partition for paging?

Comment: the function `FirstOrDefault()` doesn't return iqueryable. This means every `g.FirstOrDefault()` will run a seperate query.

Comment: its not used for paging, the ordermeta table is recording order status, like: paid, shipped, return and etc. I am trying to build a order list and each order with lastest updates from ordermeta. the sql script is works fine, but linq one not, i guess the linq what i converted is wrong?

Comment: using `FirstOrDefault` inside your select makes ef run your entire `query` query each time it is called.  Have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#linq-groupby-translation.

Comment: also in ef, look into `Skip()` and `Take()`. they are meant to work similar to partition

Comment: SO isn't really a site for asking how _working code_ can be made to run faster.  Perhaps ask on a code reviewing Stack Exchange site?

Comment: its a real site i am building @MickyD

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one hope it solve your problem

```
 public async Task<List<GetAllOrdersResult>> AdminGetOrderList()
            {
                using (var db = new SoulDrawContext())
                {
                                  var query = from A in db.Orders group A by A.OrderId into g 
                                    join B in db.OrderMeta
                                    on g.FirstOrDefault().OrderId equals B.OrderId
                                    select new GetAllOrdersResult
                                    {
                                        OrderId = g.FirstOrDefault().OrderId,
                                        UserId = g.FirstOrDefault().UserId,
                                        OrderDate = g.FirstOrDefault().OrderDate.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                        Currency = g.FirstOrDefault().Currency,
                                        Amount = g.FirstOrDefault().Amount,
                                        PaymentMethod = g.FirstOrDefault().PaymentMethod,
                                        ShipTo = g.FirstOrDefault().ShipTo,
                                        Status = B.Status,//now your B in scope so you can use Directly
                                        PostDate = B.PostDate.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"),
                                        RefOrderId = g.FirstOrDefault().RefOrderId
                                    };
                         query.OrderBy(B.PostDate);
                        return await query.ToListAsync();
                    }
           }
```

Comment: .OrderBy(B.PostDate); does not work, the OrderBy cannot put here.

Comment: thank you @CoolJK it is working now, but the query speed is almost same, not being faster T_T

Comment: maybe run raw sql is better instead linq?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155738/sql-vs-linq-performance for your answer about query.

Comment: There's a lot of `.FirstOrDefault()` on the same query in there.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I know this way for linq join with Group by.. Is there any other way than please suggest. Thanks!!